# Can I have a net equation for distance traveled?

Tags: calculus

So I was working on a problem from my Calculus textbook and I wanted to know why the approach I took to solve the problem did not work. The problem is as follows:

A subway train travels 400 feet between two stations. It starts from rest and accelerates at the rate of $8$ feet/$sec^2$ until its velocity  reaches $20$ feet/$sec$. It then moves at this constant velocity for a while and then decelerates to rest at the rate of $12$ feet/$sec^2$. Find the total time between the stations.

Where I got stuck is when I tried adding  $s(t)$  for the different segments. I found the same  $s(t)$  as the solution for the decelerating and the accelerating part which are the following  $s(t)= 4t^2$  and  $s(t)= -6t^2+20t$. However I had a different  $s(t$)  for the constant velocity portion. I had  $s(t) = 20t -25$  since I took $t_0= 2.5$  seconds and  $s(0)$ to be $25$ feet . In the solutions $s(t)$ for this portion is $20t$ . My question is why did I not get the correct answer using my own $s(t)$  ?

Comment: Why the -25? in your solution

Comment: Hey Sahi horwitz Can you please tell me what kind of modification did you do because I can't see really the difference. And I got -25 because When I solve for C in the following equation 25= 20 (2.5) +C I get -25.

Comment: we were just editing at the same time. i didn't see your edit before i posted mine. and i was just wondering because s(t)=20t-25t,s(0)=25 didnt make much sense to me. i just didnt understand what the function was trying to be.

Comment: oh ok yeah no problem.

Comment: I would treat this as a peicewise function with a continuous time. rather then 3 different functions you find the bounds that its traveling at a constant speed i.e from t=2.5 to t=start deceleration. then its clear that during this time the distance traveled is 20t

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration and deceleration last in seconds $20/8$ and $20/12$, respectively. Using these times we get the distance driven while accelerating and decelerating as $\frac{1}{2}8 \left(\frac{20}{8}\right)^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}12 \left(\frac{20}{12}\right)^2$, respectively.

The remaining distance divided by the speed is

$$\frac{400-\frac{1}{2} 8 \left(\frac{20}{8}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}12 \left(\frac{20}{12}\right)^2}{20}$$
add to that $20/8$ and $20/12$.

Comment: Hey coolwater, thanks for answering but I understand that. I am just saying why was my approach wrong. I just wanted to add the three formula for distances and equal it to 400 in order to find t. However my second formula for the distance did not match the solution which is what I don't get. I don't see how my formula for the distance in the second part of the motion is wrong.